# Clojure (deps.edn) separate integration tests

Tags: clojure, deps-edn

How do you configure `deps.edn` so you run integration tests separately from unit tests?

I have the following project tree:

```
.
├── deps.edn
├── src
│       (...)
├── test
│   └── package
│       └── test.clj
└── it
    └── package
        └── integration_test.clj
```

Desired behavior:

```sh
clj -Atest #runs unit tests only
clj -Ait   #runs integration tests only
```

Attempted configuration:

```clj
{:deps    (...)}
 :aliases {:test {:extra-paths ["test"]
                  :extra-deps  {lambdaisland/kaocha {:mvn/version "0.0-529"}}
                  :main-opts   ["-m" "kaocha.runner"]}
           :it {:extra-paths ["it"]
                :extra-deps  {lambdaisland/kaocha {:mvn/version "0.0-529"}}
                :main-opts   ["-m" "kaocha.runner"]}}}
```

Actual behavior:

```sh
clj -Atest #runs unit tests only
clj -Ait   #runs unit tests only
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to add a `tests.edn` file:

```clj
#kaocha/v1
{:tests [{:id          :unit
          :test-paths  ["test"]
          :ns-patterns [".*"]}
         {:id          :integration
          :test-paths  ["it"]
          :ns-patterns [".*"]}]}
```

And add references to the test ids defined above to `deps.edn`:

```clj
{:deps    (...)}
 :aliases {:test {:extra-paths ["test"]
                  :extra-deps  {lambdaisland/kaocha {:mvn/version "0.0-529"}}
                  :main-opts   ["-m" "kaocha.runner" "unit"]}
           :it {:extra-paths ["it"]
                :extra-deps  {lambdaisland/kaocha {:mvn/version "0.0-529"}}
                :main-opts   ["-m" "kaocha.runner" "integration"]}}}
```

Source: [`lambdaisland/kaocha`](https://github.com/lambdaisland/kaocha)